# What Sitecore Client Languages are available?

Tags: sitecore-client, multilingual

I was now wondering what the definitive list of Sitecore Client Languages actually is.
By default, my own answer would be English, Danish, German and Japanese.

However I found this: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_update2.aspx
where Dutch, Swedish, French, Norwegian and Chinese are also mentioned.

And one would expect that list to be followed through into each and every next version... However, for later versions (8.2/9) we seem to fall back into the default list of English, Danish, German and Japanese

So, what is the correct list and to what extent can we use that full list to, in my case, offer the client environment in French or Dutch?

Comment: Speaking from experience, if a client is big enough and requires a specific client language that is not supported (Spanish in my example), Sitecore will make it happen. I too am surprised this isn't more standardized.

Comment: I agree, as it is a one time job to get this translated with a minimal upkeep cost this should be relatively easy to maintain and provide